# Save DOM Element using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, load, save

I have this video element in my webpage:

```
    <video height="240" width="412" id="video" controls="controls">
    </video>
<button type="button"  id ="url_go" name="url_go" onclick="showUploadDiv()"> Load </button>
<form id="upload" action="save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<button type="submit" > Save </button>
```

and it has a dynamic url loaded in this way:

```
function showUploadDiv()
{
    if ($("#url").val()==null || $("#url").val()=="")
        return false; 

    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.src = $("#url").val();
    video.controls = true;
    video.height = 240; 
    video.width = 412;
    document.getElementById('url').value="";
}
```

I upload a video (set the value url) in my webpage with the button `load`. After that I want to save my element `video`.
My problem is in the file `save.php`, where I want to save the video element with the new URL loaded. In this code I save the webpage elements in a new webpage but the video hasn't the url value loaded:

```
<?php
    $ourFileName = "testFile.html";
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, file_get_contents("index.html"));
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
?>
```

Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Not sure I get this at all? Are you saying the user types in a link to a video, and then you would play that video on your site, and you would also like to save the actual video on the server ?

Comment: you are only changing the content of the page in the users browsers.  It's not like the page gets saved to the server when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the DOM in the user's browser with JavaScript, the original HTML file on the server is not actually changed. You will need to upload the URL, and manually insert the "src" attribute into the HTML code you load, before saving it.

```
<?php
    $ourFileName = "testFile.html";
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
    $url = $_POST['url']; // don't forget to validate this
    $content = file_get_contents("index.html");
    $content = str_replace('<video ','<video src="'.$url.'" ',$content);
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $content);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
?>
```